# How can I compress and encrypt a large file without using external DLLs or runtimes?

Tags: delphi, encryption, compression, components

I am looking for a component or other technique to compress and encrypt multiple large files (files which exceed 4gb in size, and thus will not fit in the memory available to a win32 process) into a single file.  I would like the encryption to be very strong (256 bit AES or better) but the compression doesn't matter to me.

Right now, I'm using the `TJvZlibMultiple` component which creates its own non-Zip file format, but I have to create the archive, then encrypt it in a separate step (I'm using DcpCrypt right now).  I'd like to do the same in a single pass, using streams, without using memory equal to the size of the file (ergo, the compression and encryption should happen with streams, and not in memory).

I have seen, and don't want to use, anything that requires an external DLLs like the 7zip dll. Commercial tools are okay, or any code or sample Delphi sources, but I'm looking for a thorough implementation within Delphi not a thing that imports and invokes functions in a dll.

Comment: I disagree with the 2 votes for closing! (esp without any explanation).

Comment: @François, the two votes were both that the question wasn't constructive, which in this context probably means they objected to the solicitation of components because it borders on a poll question. I've taken it a little farther from that border by making it ask the more general question of how to accomplish the stated goal instead of asking specifically for a component. Most answers will probably suggest components or libraries anyway.

Comment: Thanks @RobKennedy. It looks indeed better like that.

Comment: I ended up using a customized version of TJvZLibMultiple from Jedi JVCL, plus encryption from DCPCrypt, because I couldn't live with the limitations of DIZipWriter, listed below.  But if DIZipWriter ever works with 64-bit-era file sizes (Int64), I'll re-mark it as the answer.

Comment: The SO community is pretty cancerous with all these "high rep" people voting to close questions, marking duplicates randomly and editing people's questions as they wish, they should revoke all these powers from mere users.

Comment: @hikari From the [help/on-topic]: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_ FYI I voted to close. You can flag such questions for closure with the "flag" link.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [DIZipWriter](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/zipwriter/index).

Supports 256 bit AES, streaming and compression.

Update:
Version 5 claims to have support for large sized (64bit) entries, [`DIZipWriter History`](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/zipwriter/history).

Comment: I removed the answer flag from this question because although this component has beautiful encryption support it uses Cardinal (32 bit) instead of int64 for file-size and position parameters, meaning that the developer has not thought about using his component with files > 4 gb in size. As that was the easy part, I didn't even begin to suspect that he would have botched such an easy thing. But looking at the downloadable version (which lets you see the signatures of all the APIs), I can see it's not ready for Large Files.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at FlexCompress by ComponentAce: http://www.componentace.com/compression_component_compression_delphi_encryption_delphi_flexcompress.htm

Comment: More expensive than DIZipWriter, at 79 euros.  Still, quite good.

Answer (score -1):

Check FlexCompress:

FlexCompress is a compression delphi component designed for creating archives with strong encryption and better compression rate than WinZip and RAR. Native VCL, no DLLs, no OCXs, provides compression for files, buffers, streams and strings, supports in-memory archives, compresses large files > 4 Gb with low memory consumption and lots of other useful features.

http://www.componentace.com/flexcompress_features.htm

by this link: http://delphi.about.com/od/toppicks/tp/delphi_zip.htm

Comment: Already suggest above. Makes your answer duplicate. Just up vote please,